# Does JasperCompileManager.compileReport(...) cache templates?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have this Java code snippet:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
long compileTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
logger.info("Compile template time : " + compileTime);
```

I'm measuring the time it takes to compile a Jasper report template using JasperCompileManager. I've noticed that every time I pass in a new report template, the first compilation always takes longer than subsequent ones.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Is it because JasperCompileManager caches the compiled report template?

I have tried to read the source code of JasperReports, but I don't understand it very well.